# how do i manipulate a link or a link's parent if the html in the link equals something?

Tags: php, jquery, css, database, variables

**EDIT:** may have messed up the question.  meant "if the html in the link equals a php variable"

so let's say we have an unordered list menu on a page where database values are coming in.  i want to add active class to a link that has same value as a database variable.  how do i do that?  i would like to be able to do it with text values and number values.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">text1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">text2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">text3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">500</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">1000</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">1500</a></li>
</ul>
```

so let's say these variables are on the page:

```
$var1 & $var2
```

echoing those out like this:

```
<p><?php echo $var1; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $var2; ?></p>
```

would print these values out:

```
text1
1000
```

so what i want to do is some php and jquery that would do these things:

if $var1 equals text1 then do one of these 2 on the 1st ul list.  doesn't matter which:

```
<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">text1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active">text1</a></li>
```

if $var1 equals text2 then the second list item on the 1st ul list should get active class on the "li" or "a".

if $var1 equals text3 then the third list item on the 1st ul list should get active class on the "li" or "a".

if $var2 equals 500 then the first list item on the 2nd ul list should get active class on the "li" or "a".

if $var2 equals 1000 then the second list item on the 2nd ul list should get active class on the "li" or "a".

if $var2 equals 1500 then the third list item on the 2nd ul list should get active class on the "li" or "a".

Comment: Why aren't you generating the menu in code and changing the output directly?

Comment: menu is all by itself in a php file with no logic or variable capability.  it's included into another php page which has all the php and jquery logic.

Comment: You should refactor your code. Hacking in the active state after the fact is the wrong way to do this.

Comment: @loarce: every php file has logic capabilities! Just because it's included doesn't mean you can't write code in there. Sounds like static markup at the moment. As your site grows larger, the menu will be generated dynamically, giving you the option to sneak in active classes easily..

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you wouldn't influence the HTML markup while it's being generated on the server, since I assume you've got the variables on the server already - probably coming from a client request (page navigation?). However, to answer your question:

### Traversal and manipulation of DOM elements

You'll need the variables available on the client running Javascript. Then, you could loop through the `li`s and compare their value with the variables. Once a match is found, you can make the adjustments to your DOM element (i.e. [jQuery addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)).

For looping see [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), and [jQuery text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for the text content of an element.

### How to get the variables into Javascript:

As stated above, this requires Javascript to 'know' these variables. There's no magic to make that work. You'll have to get them from the server, either it's included as Javascript code in the page originally requested from the server (like when you do http://www.example.com/index.html) *or* your Javascript code makes a XMLHttpRequest to the server (see [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for that) and parses the variables out of the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an inline `if` statement like so

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="<?php echo $var1 == "text1" ? "active":"" ?>">text1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="<?php echo $var1 == "text2" ? "active":"" ?>">text2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="<?php echo $var1 == "text3" ? "active":"" ?>">text3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="<?php echo $var2 == "500" ? "active":"" ?>">500</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="<?php echo $var2 == "1000" ? "active":"" ?>">1000</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="<?php echo $var2 == "1500" ? "active":"" ?>">1500</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the same exact menu is being used many different times on the page.  only way this could work is if $var1 can be changed to $var2 or $var3 or $var4 or $var5 or $var6 on the fly in the appropriate places of the page.

Answer (score 0):

i did it a different way.

first i put unique class names to all the menu items.  i used classes instead of id's because each menu it used multiple times on the page.

then i used this code to produce the active css...

```
<?php if($varset1a == "500") { ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#idname1a ul.classname li.classname1").addClass("active"); });</script>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($varset1a == "1000") { ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#idname1b ul.classname li.classname2").addClass("active"); });</script>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($varset2a == "name1") { ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#anotheridname1 ul.classname li.anotherclassname1").addClass("active"); });</script>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($varset2a == "name2") { ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#anotheridname2 ul.classname li.anotherclassname2").addClass("active"); });</script>
<?php } ?>
```

there are 2 sets of menus, and each set has 6 variables, and each menu has many links, so the above has to be copy and pasted many times to cover all the combinations.  the above is just 2 rules for set one, and 2 rules for set two.  there are many more rules than those.

let's say it's about this many:

varset1a1 through varset1a17

then varset1b has 1 through 17, then varset1c has 1 through 17, then varset1d has 1 through 17, then varset1e has 1 through 17.

then double all those and change varset1 to varset2, and that's about how many different rules there are.  actually more because menu 2 has more links than menu 1.

it's a lot to program, but only 6 lines per menu gets produced in html source code.

this is an example if all 6 from both menus are used.  it would be less if less menus are used.  the amount of menus used varies, but this is the full amount:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id1a ul.class li.class1a").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id2a ul.class li.class2a").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id3a ul.class li.class3a").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id4a ul.class li.class4a").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id5a ul.class li.class5a").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id6a ul.class li.class6a").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id1b ul.class li.class1b").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id2b ul.class li.class2b").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id3b ul.class li.class3b").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id4b ul.class li.class4b").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id5b ul.class li.class5b").addClass("active"); });</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $("#id6b ul.class li.class7b").addClass("active"); });</script>
```

maybe i can cut down on characters if i make it all go in between one < script > tag set and one document ready clause?  i hate putting php in between jquery, because many times dreamweaver produces syntax errors.

EDIT:

ok, now the full html output is like this and it still works:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id1a ul.class li.class1a").addClass("active");
  $("#id2a ul.class li.class2a").addClass("active");
  $("#id3a ul.class li.class3a").addClass("active");
  $("#id4a ul.class li.class4a").addClass("active");
  $("#id5a ul.class li.class5a").addClass("active");
  $("#id6a ul.class li.class6a").addClass("active");
  $("#id1b ul.class li.class1b").addClass("active");
  $("#id2b ul.class li.class2b").addClass("active");
  $("#id3b ul.class li.class3b").addClass("active");
  $("#id4b ul.class li.class4b").addClass("active");
  $("#id5b ul.class li.class5b").addClass("active");
  $("#id6b ul.class li.class7b").addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

the way i did that was by putting the rules like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() { 
<?php if($varset1a == "500") { ?>$("#id1a ul.class li.class1a").addClass("active");<?php } ?>
<?php if($varset1a == "1000") { ?>$("#id2b ul.class li.class2a").addClass("active");<?php } ?>
<?php if($varset2a == "name1") { ?>$("#id2a ul.class li.class1b").addClass("active");<?php } ?>
<?php if($varset2a == "name2") { ?>$("#id2b ul.class li.class2b").addClass("active");<?php } ?>
});
</script>
```